# Performing Restkit configuration via a class method in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, restkit, class-method

In an effort to clean up my application delegate I have moved Restkit configuration (ie, starting with `[RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[MYAppConfig wsBaseUrl]];`) to another class `MYAppConfig` in a static method `+(RKObjectManager *)defaultObjectManager`.

At the very real risk of exposing my ignorance I am not sure whether this is a legitimate reorganization or could lead to trouble, mainly because I am not sure how Restkit's singleton is implemented (it seems like, based on the tutorials I have read, it gets created when you call the class method `managerWithBaseURL`).

What is driving my suspicion is that RestKit's logging functions do not seem to be firing when I make a fetch request.

The whole thing now kind of goes like this:

In `MYAppDelegate.m` method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, first line:

`[self _setup]`

In `MYAppDelegate.m` method `_setup`

```
[self _setupORM];

RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/CoreData", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

In `MYAppDelegate.m` method `_setupORM`

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [MYAppConfig defaultObjectManager];
NSLog(@"Setup ORM with object manager %@",[manager description]);
```

In `MYAppConfig.m` class method `defaultObjectManager`

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[MYAppConfig wsBaseUrl]];

NSManagedObjectModel *managedModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedModel];

manager.managedObjectStore = managedStore;
...
[managedStore createManagedObjectContexts];

managedStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

return manager;
```

Should I look elsewhere to see why logging appears to be failing or might it have something to do with how I have structured the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intention is good and the implementation also looks correct. Your guess about the `sharedManager` is also correct, but only for the first instantiation (so if you were to be calling `managerWithBaseURL:` in 2 places and not fully configuring the first time, nothing would work - check that the original code was all removed).

Comment: Thanks, it indeed turned out to be an entirely different issue that was causing the RestKit issues.